# Msal handleRedirectPromise gives the response late. How to get msal handleRedirectPromise response first and then execute rest of the code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, azure-ad-msal

Msal handleRedirectPromise gives the response late and goes for login secong time because of which I'm getting error 'BrowserAuthError: interaction_in_progress'. How to get msal handleRedirectPromise response first and then execute rest of the code.

auth.service code
`

```
this.msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise().then(
            res => {
              if (res != null && res.account != null) {
                this.msalInstance.setActiveAccount(res.account)
              }
            });
```

`

```
 public get userInfo(): AccountInfo | null {
    debugger;
    //return this.context.getCachedUser();
    const currentAccounts = this.msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
    return currentAccounts[0];
  }
```

login.component code

```
if (this.auth.userInfo) {
    this.auth.checkUserAuthorization(this.auth.userInfo.username).subscribe((res) => {
        const message = res.Role !== null ? res : res.toLowerCase();
        if (message === 'User Not Exist') {
          this.router.navigate(['/notAuthorise']); // If user not Authorized then navigate to notAuthorize page
        } else {
         this.auth.setUserLoggedIn(true);
          this.router.navigate(['/appHeader']);
        }
      }, (err) => {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      });
    
      this.router.navigate(['/appHeader']);  // navigate to PAA Data Collection page if User Information is Authenticated
    }
    else {
        this.auth.login();
      }
```

[image]

Any help will be useful. Thanks in advance.